# System.StackOverflowException on BlogEngine.NET

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I am using BlogEngine.NET and need to set the BlogId to a specific Guid (blogIdstr). I can't seem to figure out how to change it from the default blogId. This is the code I have at the moment but it is giving me a StackOverflowException...

These two are in the base class...

```
public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }

public Guid BlogId 
{ 
get 
   { 
       return BlogId; <-- Stack Overflow
   }

set
   {
       string blogIdstr = "FCA96EFB-D51C-4C41-9F85-3EEB9C50BDE7";
       Guid blogIdGuid = Guid.Empty;
       blogIdGuid = Guid.Parse(blogIdstr);
   }
}
```

And this one is in blog.cs...

```
public override Guid Id
{
get { return base.Id; }
set
{
    base.Id = value;
    base.BlogId = value;
}
}
```

How can I set the blogId and avoid the StackOverflowException? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a recursive function with no exit condition, of course it overflows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to introduce a backing variable

`private Guid _blogId;` and be sure to set that field in your `set` method

```
public Guid BlogId 
{ 
get 
   { 
       return _blogId; 
   }

set
   {
       string blogIdstr = "FCA96EFB-D51C-4C41-9F85-3EEB9C50BDE7";
       Guid blogIdGuid = Guid.Empty;
       blogIdGuid = Guid.Parse(blogIdstr);

       _blogId = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, in BlogId, you're returning BlogId, which fires the Getter that returns... BlogId.  Boom, stack overflow.  Return blogIdGuid in your public getter instead of BlogId.

I'm guessing the second one is related to the first, but without more code I can't tell offhand.

Edit: Whoops, misread the code.  Yeah, use a backing class-level property called _blogId and set that in the setter and return it in the getter.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get` method is calling itself, and your `set` method is essentially issuing a no-op by setting a value local to the method. You need a backing field for your property if you want to do something inside of the getter and setter:

```
private Guid _blogId;
public Guid BlogId 
{ 
   get 
   { 
       return _blogId;
   }

   set
   {
       //some operation against value here, Validate(value), etc.
       _blogId = value;
   }
}
```

If you have no action to take in the getter/setter, you can use an [auto property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), which will generate the backing field for you:

```
public Guid BlogId { get; set; }
```

What you *can't* do, and what it appears you're really trying to do here, is pass a different type into a property - to do that you'd need a method on the class, i.e.:

```
public bool TrySetBlogId(string newId)
{
    Guid id;
    var stringIsGuid = Guid.TryParse(newId, out id);

    if (stringIsGuid)
    {
        BlogId = id;
    }

    return stringIsGuid;
}
```